# ActiveAdmin: Can I redirect the user to the index after they create/edit something?

Tags: activeadmin

My customer (who is nontechnical) has asked me if I can change an ActiveAdmin form to redirect to the index instead of the show-item page after she submits (assuming no form errors).

Is that possible?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that was a lot easier than I expected.

For my `Articles` model,

```
ActiveAdmin.register Article do

  ...

  controller do
    def create
      create! { admin_articles_url }
    end 
    def update
      update! { admin_articles_url }
    end 
  end 

  ...

end
```

That's it!

This is implemented by the [`inherited_resources` gem](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources), which Active Admin uses.  My code changes are actually right from that project's readme.